# Are spin-1/4 theories forbidden?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, group-representations

Ok, this question looks a bit ridiculous at the outset. However, I was thinking, and I couldn't actually come up with a reason why there shouldn't exist a [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group) of the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) that was, say, spin-$1/4$. These wouldn't be spinors, and I don't exactly know what they would look like, but I can't find any reason to prevent them from existing.

Therefore, are such theories forbidden? If so, why? If not, can any such theory ever be physically relevant?

Comment: It's only okay for SO(2). They're called parafermions.

Comment: ... or its covering space, $\mathbb R$.

Comment: related: [What is the physical implication(s) of the isomorphism between ${\rm SO}(2)$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380352/84967).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning here; isn't the reason we have spin-1/2 particles is because the universal cover of the Lorentz group is a double cover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lorentz group, SO(1,3) has a universal cover that is a double cover, Spin(1,3).

This is the origin of spin-1/2.

This suggests that had we a spacetime which had a rotation group $G$ whose universal cover $UG$ was a quadruple cover then we ought to find that this theory has spin-1/4 particles.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would such a spacetime look like (with a quadruple cover)?

Comment: @riemanntensor: I've no idea! It would be toy theory at best in the sense of formal physics to see what such a world would look like. It might be worth a thesis if someone wanted to pursue it systematically ;).

Comment: A quadruple cover of a group A by another group B is possible iff the Lie-manifold of the group A is 4-fold connected or, in other words, the fundamental homotopy group of this manifold is discrete with cardinality 4.

Comment: @DanielC: I was wondering about what Lie groups admit quadruple covers. Thanks for filling me in. Is this a specialisation of [n-connectedness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected_space) to the case *n* equals 4?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Note also: Poincaré admits continuous-spin representations for massless particles, for any number of spacetime diemensions. But these representations are dynamically pathological, so they are rarely considered.

Answer (score 2):

In 2D you can have anyons, which can have any spin.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon